# download CSV file in IE

Tags: javascript, csv, internet-explorer

I`ve used the code below to download CSV file in IE, the download is successful.
But the file is encoding in Unicode, not utf-8.
How can I save the file in utf-8.

```
if (document.execCommand) {
        var oWin = window.open("about:blank", "_blank");
        oWin.document.charset = "UTF-8";
        oWin.document.write(csvOutput);
        oWin.document.close();
        oWin.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, FILENAME);
        oWin.close();
    }
```

Comment: You need to add more tags so that your question can reach good people. Is IE, Internet Explorer...?

Comment: Thank you, added some more tags. Yes, it`s Internet Explorer.

Comment: <a href="data.csv" target="_blank">Open me in your default csv file handler or right-click and select 'Save target as' from the context menu</a>